SVG image download with Kingfisher
SVG, PNG images coming from api. I couldn't download SVG image with Kingfisher.
I tried this code but I got error. How can I fix this problem ? How can I download SVG image.
SVGImgProcessor:
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
import SVGKit

public struct SVGImgProcessor: ImageProcessor {
    public var identifier: String = "com.appidentifier.webpprocessor"
    
    public func process(item: ImageProcessItem, options: KingfisherParsedOptionsInfo) -> KFCrossPlatformImage? {
        switch item {
        case .image(let image):
            print("already an image")
            return image
        case .data(let data):
            let imsvg = SVGKImage(data: data)
            return imsvg?.uiImage
        }
    }
}

CoinItemCell:
final class CoinItemCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var coinImageView: UIImageView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
   
    func prepareCell(with item: CoinItemVM) {
        itemLabel.text = item.name
        let processor = SVGImgProcessor()
        coinImageView.kf.setImage(with: item.coinImage, options: [.processor(processor)])
    }
}

Error:
*** Assertion failure in +[SVGLength pixelsPerInchForCurrentDevice], SVGLength.m:238
*** Assertion failure in void _UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize, BOOL, CGFloat, BOOL)(), UIGraphics.m:410
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() failed to allocate CGBitampContext: size={0, 0}, scale=3.000000, bitmapInfo=0x2002. Use UIGraphicsImageRenderer to avoid this assert.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180491128 __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018008412c objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   Foundation                          0x0000000180d11770 -[NSMutableDictionary(NSMutableDictionary) classForCoder] + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000184e9af20 _UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions + 564
    4   CoinList                            0x00000001009ba370 +[SVGKExporterUIImage exportAsUIImage:antiAliased:curveFlatnessFactor:interpolationQuality:] + 388
    5   CoinList                            0x00000001009cfbe0 -[SVGKImage UIImage] + 56
    6   CoinList                            0x000000010084ce78 $s8CoinList15SVGImgProcessorV7process4item7optionsSo7UIImageCSg10Kingfisher16ImageProcessItemO_AJ0I17ParsedOptionsInfoVtF + 492
    7   CoinList                            0x000000010084d230 $s8CoinList15SVGImgProcessorV10Kingfisher05ImageD0AadEP7process4item7optionsSo7UIImageCSgAD0F11ProcessItemO_AD0E17ParsedOptionsInfoVtFTW + 20
    8   CoinList                            0x0000000100915b48 $s10Kingfisher18ImageDataProcessorC9doProcess33_6119A2C527FFA834F85B326B80E79A62LLyyF + 1164
    9   CoinList                            0x00000001009156ac $s10Kingfisher18ImageDataProcessorC7processyyFyycACcfu_yycfu0_ + 36
    10  CoinList                            0x0000000100956e40 $s10Kingfisher13CallbackQueueO7executeyyyycFyyYbcfU1_ + 64
    11  CoinList                            0x000000010086351c $sIegh_IeyBh_TR + 48
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101d180f0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101d1993c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101d21bd8 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 916
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101d2291c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 420
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101d2f2f8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 324
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101d2e754 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 488
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000101db3924 _pthread_wqthread + 284
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000101db26e4 start_wqthread + 8
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException


This is My SVGImageProcessor:

import UIKit
import PocketSVG
import Kingfisher
struct SVGImgProcessor: ImageProcessor {
    let identifier = "svgimgprocessor"
    let size: CGSize
    init(size: CGSize = .init(width: 24, height: 24)) {
        self.size = size
    }
    func process(item: ImageProcessItem,
                 options: KingfisherParsedOptionsInfo) -> KFCrossPlatformImage? {
        switch item {
        case .image(let image):
            return image
        case .data(let data):
            if let svgString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                let path = SVGBezierPath.paths(fromSVGString: svgString)
                let layer = SVGLayer()
                layer.paths = path
                let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
                layer.frame = frame
                let img = self.snapshotImage(for: layer)
                return img
            }
            return nil
        }
    }

    func snapshotImage(for view: CALayer) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        view.render(in: context)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}

and also you can use (don't forget import "Kingfisher") :
imageView.kf.setImage(with: imURL, options: [.processor(SVGImgProcessor())])

and also this links maybe can help you:
https://gist.github.com/saish98/b848fc279ee0a1f87fb6afc20bcc0f33
https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/issues/1225
